# Server side licensing and bypassing in-app purchasing

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, appstore-approval

We have a model where a "license" dictates the period it is valid and how many devices are "allowed" to run against it. The "main" application will manage the license and the "children" applications will use the license code to check validity and provide functionality to the end user.

Currently both the applications will be deployed on both iOS and Android but we do not feel the relevant App Store and Play Store policies and features allow us to cover the needs here with their in-app purchasing. Again, the "main" application is to issue and pay for a license that the "child" application will use.

As such, will it be an issue to deploy on the stores an application which uses our own credit card system to charge for license purchase and renewal given that the purchase will be done in one application but in essence used by another application?

Comment: On iOS at least, you will need to collec the payment outside of the app using a website or similar. The app cannot contain a link to the web site or open the web site to process the payment. Purchases made in the app for features delivered in the app must be made through Apple's in app purchase process

Comment: We recognize this but the license features are not for the app itself but rather for the "child" applications. So we are purchasing from "main" application to enable "child" applications.

Comment: Well, only Apple can answer your question, but in my opinion your app will be rejected.

Comment: Even if your main app was approved, your child app is likely to be rejected for violating 3.1.4 https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments

Comment: Good point - thank you Paulw11